# how to add findone for name validation in nodejs details from mongodb

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, express, mean-stack

anyone of you can slove this problem the duplication of name to avoid and execute on postman api the codes are attached below

*employeemodel.js[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/74ZNy.png)

*employeecontroller.js[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BqzMp.png)

*routes.js[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sPrM1.png)

Comment: I don't think anyone will understand your question, you should revise it.

Comment: And please don't use images, post your code!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understood your question correctly. But if you would like to prevent double names in your EmployeeModel, you can use [Unique Indexes](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/index-unique/) like `unique: true` in your `employeemodel.js`:

```
const employeeSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true
  }
})
```

On saving a new model with an existing name, in `employeeController.js` on `await employeeModelData.save()` you will get an error, this will be caught with your try-catch.

If you need further information and examples, you can take a look on: [Understanding unique in Mongoose](https://masteringjs.io/tutorials/mongoose/unique).